# Java Array declaration like { A[] aa = new B[10]}

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Today I've written simple test about syntax of declaring array, so, there are 3 classes:

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends A {
}
```

and I've tried to create array using next syntax

```
A[] aa = new B[10];
```

So, It is possible, but we can added just instances of class `B` to this array , If you will try to add instances of `A` or `C` you receive [java.lang.ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) and question, Why can we create array using syntax like that and where is it can be used and make some profit ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this syntax is allowed in the language is that sometimes you don't care what subclass of objects are in the array. The [Java Language Specification rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) for array subtyping include:

> If *S* and *T* are both reference types, then *S[]* ><sub>1</sub> *T[]* iff *S* ><sub>1</sub> *T*.

(where ><sub>1</sub> means "direct subtype").

This allows one to write a method like this:

```
public void printArray(Object[] array) {
    System.out.print('[');
    boolean first = true;
    for (Object obj : array) {
        if (!first) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(obj));
    }
    System.out.print(']');
}
```

and then call it with:

```
String[] foo = { "a", "b", "c" };
printArray(foo);
```

This language feature does have the unfortunate effect of deferring ArrayStoreException problems to run time.

Comment: Thanks, Yep, it is just a one way of using that I've invented.

Answer (score 4):

The array holds type Bs.  Even though the reference aa could hold arrays of type A[], B[] or C[], (since C and B both extend A), at runtime, the array can only hold things which are Bs.

Class A is not a B.  Class C is not a B.  Hence the runtime exception.

EDIT:

There are many potential uses for code like this.  For example, You can declare an array like this because you might not know until runtime the more explicit type you are working with.

For instance:

```
Animal[] animals;
if (useDogs) {
 animals = new Dog[num];
} else {
 animals = new Cat[num];
}

loadIntoCar(animals);
```

Comment: And where  answers to my questions, I fully understand what is happening but why can we declare arrays like that?

Comment: I thought about this situation but decided that is problem in architecture, I am about your edit

Answer (score 0):

Arrays types are [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29), which means you can declare A[] a = new B[] (Collections, on the contrary, are not : you cannot declare List<A> a = new List<B>()).

This is why the compiler cannot preemptively check that you will only put elements of a valid type in the array, which explains why the check happens only at runtime, when you try to insert an element into the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want examples, take a look at [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). If Java didn't allow arrays polymorphism, we couldn't have functionalities such as `sort(Object[] a)`, `toString(Object[] a)`, `binarySearch(Object[] a, Object key)`, etc. Remember that `B`and `C` are subtypes of `Object`, so you can use that functionality for all of them. Take note that arrays predate generics (Java 1.5.0) and that even generics have it's flaws (the trade-off for Java is that you can't know the generic type at runtime because of type-erasure).